# Windows Terminal Server shows duplicate printers with "driver is unavailable" that can't be removed

Tags: windows, server, printing

In my windows server configured as terminal server, in the user "printer and drivers" I see some printers that are not installed, these printers don't show up in print management console and if I delete "remove device" button it doesn't work.

Theese printers has the same name of printers that I uninstalled.

How can I remove theese printers?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Registry Editor by typing "regedit" in the Start menu search bar and pressing Enter.

Navigate to the following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers

Look for the entries that correspond to the phantom printers. You can identify them by their names, which should match the names of the printers you uninstalled.

Right-click on the entry and select "Delete" to remove it.

Confirm that you want to delete the entry by clicking "Yes" in the dialog box.

Repeat steps 4-5 for each phantom printer that you want to remove.

Close the Registry Editor and restart the Print Spooler service by typing "services.msc" in the Start menu search bar, finding the "Print Spooler" service, right-clicking it, and selecting "Restart."

After you have completed these steps, the phantom printers should be removed from the list of printers available to your users. However, it's always a good idea to make a backup of your registry before making any changes, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I already tried that, but the phantom printers doesn't appear in the registry